# Stop iframe autoplaying with mp4 files

Tags: iframe

I want to stop a .mp4 file in an iframe from autoplaying.

The code is simple:

```
var siteVidUrl = document.createElement("iframe");  // create iframe
siteVidUrl.src = Obj.URL + "?autoplay=0"; // create src attribute for iframe
link_col.appendChild(siteVidUrl); // append to DOM
```

An example of Obj.URL would be

```
media.website.com/theVideo.mp4
```

The video contines to autoplay, despite my best attempts. As you can see, I am appending "?autoplay=0", to the end of the src attribute URL, but no luck there. I have read a bit about the video HTML5 tag, but no luck there either...

The majority of the videos are .mp4 files.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to use an iframe for this? If not have look at the HTML5 video-tag: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_video.asp

If the iframe is needed (for any reason), you could set the src to a page which receives the URL of the video as a parameter and just produces the HTML containing a simple video-tag in it. This way you'll be able to control the video playback and disable autoplay.